# Android SetText not working on TextVIew but the value is there

Tags: java, php, android, sql

Guys I am trying to set the `Textview` but it's not changing, the value from the database is there. i hope someone can help

here's the java code

```
public class Announcement_Details extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final String GET_URL = "http://XXX";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TextView id,title,content,date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lv_view);
        id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_content);
        date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

        getAnnouncementDetails();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.refresh) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void getAnnouncementDetails() {
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GET_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray data = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("announcement_data");
                            Log.d("Announcement Data", ""+data);
                            id.setText(data.getString(0));
                            title.setText(data.getString(1));
                            content.setText(data.getString(2));
                            date.setText(data.getString(3));

                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                // the POST parameters:
                params.put("id", getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
                return params;
            }
        };

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Announcement_Details.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Announcements Details.");
        pDialog.show();

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplication()).add(postRequest);


    }
}
```

here's the value from logcat

```
02-05 01:28:35.861    4004-4004/com.example.wackyroad.internannouncement D/Announcement Data﹕ [{"announcement_title":"Sample Title Here","announcement_content":"Sample Content","announcement_date":"2016-02-04"}]
```

Comment: Json array contains JsonObject so you need to get that before adding set to textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in parsing Data - 
Please see this -

```
title.setText(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_title"));//announcement_title
        content.setText(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_content"));//announcement_content
        date.setText(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_date"));//announcement_date
```

Here is Very Important link of parsing data - [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not proper parsing data, try this snippets will be helpfull

```
title.setText(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_title")); 
                      content.setText(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_content"));  
                     date.setText(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_date"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[{"announcement_title":"Sample Title Here",  //  0 pos
"announcement_content":"Sample Content",  //  1 pos
"announcement_date":"2016-02-04"}]  //  2 pos
```

Your json array Size is 3 but you are retrieving 4 items.

```
 id.setText(data.getString(0));
 title.setText(data.getString(1));
 content.setText(data.getString(2));
 date.setText(data.getString(3)); //remove this one
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This will not gonna work at all, we can't get the value without key.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Id in your Json data.

Parse data from you JsonArray for given response and get the JsonObject from the array. Then parse the details from the JsonObject.

```
 String title =  data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_title");
 String content = data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_content");
 String date = data.getJSONObject(0).getString("announcement_date");
```

Set the json data to TextView's:

```
 title.setText(title); 
 content.setText(content);                                                                
 date.setText(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

your json data is like this as i given below:-

[{"announcement_title":"Sample Title Here","announcement_content":"Sample Content","announcement_date":"2016-02-04"}]

There is no Id in your Json data:-

//comment Id settext this line because no Id in your Json data

//id.setText(data.getString(0));

So you have to change your index value as give below in code:-

title.setText(data.getString(0));

content.setText(data.getString(1));

date.setText(data.getString(2));